# How to deploy one particular DAG post environment creation in google cloud composer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, airflow, google-cloud-composer, terraform-provider-gcp

We creating multiple GCP composer environment using terraform, every time we create a new environment we have to upload few dags which are used for health-check and operational purposes.

Is there any automated way where post environment creation those dags will be copied from cloud storage bucket to the newly created DAGs folder in the bucket OR Is there a way to achieve it using terraform !!

We ca use cloud scheduler to run the copy process but it will not know that new composer is created, we have to manually trigger it.

Thanks in advance for any help !!

Comment: Does this [link](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/4779) help you?

Comment: @pushpendudhara can you check my answer please ? I hope it will help you to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following page of official documentation can help you https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/managing-dags

> On the list of environments, find a row with the name of your environment and in the DAGs folder column click the DAGs link. The Bucket details page opens. It shows contents of the /dags folder in your environment's bucket.

You can just sync your bucket with the default Dag folder using Terraform.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not the responsability of `Terraform` to do such of action.
`Terraform` has the responsability to manage the infra of your `Composer` cluster (infra as code).

You can delegate this responsability in your CI CD part.
For example, if you have a `Cloud Build` job that launches your `Terraform apply`, you can add a following step that copies your expected DAGs in the `Composer` bucket.

You can manage this need in a different ways :

- Automatic step after the Terraform apply
- If you prefer, you can launch a manual step with a separate job to deploy your DAG when as you want. It depends on the best strategy for you, but it's a concern which should be managed on the CI CD part.

For these examples, I used `Cloud Build` but the principle is the same for any CI CD tool (`Gitlab CI`, `Github Actions`, `Cloud Build`...)